# Trigger a workflow when item is created by sending email to SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have assigned an email address `mylist@office1.xyz.com` to a sharepoint calendar list.

When I send an email to this calendar list email address, the list is updated and it reflects the meeting i created via outlook and also saves the attachment as `.ics`.

However, I want to further trigger a workflow to forward this new item to a SharePoint group. So essentially, when I create an event by sending email to this calendar list, I want a workflow to automatically send another email to a group of users.

The challenge is, it works when I manually create entry within the list and the email is sent; however when the entry is created by sending email to the list email address, the workflow doesn't trigger and no email is sent.

Please suggest.
Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Items created through email upload using the system account (even though "Created By" shows the user who sent the email). This is because there's a setting that allows you to receive incoming email from external users.

From this [link](http://www.sharepointmaestra.com/Blog/Post/1/Workflow-2013-Not-Starting-on-Incoming-Email):

> For 2013 Workflows, the fix is to enable the "Workflows can use app permissions" ​feature on the site followed by an IISRESET.

Comment: Thanks Erin, When I go to the site features and try to activate "workflow can use app permissions" I get this error message..........Sorry, something went wrong 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Technical Details 


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 06119d9d-dbbe-8060-b23b-30840969a456 

Date and Time: 25/08/2016 00:30:01

Comment: Can you find that correlation id in your logs and give us the error message?